# How to Return Single-Digit Counts after Numbers are Randomly Generated (Java,Arrays)

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a program that generates 100 random integers between
0 and 9 and displays the count for each number.

```
    int[] counts = new int[10]; // Array of ten integers

    // Store the counts of 100 random numbers
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        counts[(int)(Math.random() * 10)]++;
    }

    // Display the results
    System.out.println("Count for each number between 0 and 9:");
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "s: " + counts[i]);
    }
```

Now I am being asked to write a program that generates 1000 random integers between 0 and 99, and display the number of times each single-digit number (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ..., 9) was generated. How can I modify this code to do that?

Update:This code is now fixed. Here is the updated version for anyone who needs it. Thanks to everyone who responded so fast!

```
int[] counts = new int[100]; 


    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        counts[(int)(Math.random() * 100)]++;
    }


    System.out.println("Count for each number between 0 and 9:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "s: " + counts[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Change the array size to int[100]. Then change the 100 in the for loop to 1000, and change the * 10 to * 100

Comment: @NickParsons I made the changes to my code doing exactly what you said, but the program displays the counts of numbers from 0-99. I need it to display the counts only of single-digit characters (0-9).

Comment: If you want to do that change `count.length` in your last for loop to `10` (so you only display the first 10 index of your array (0-9))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on *magic numbers*, extract the values which drive your logic. The maximum number and the count are what is changing. Make those variables. Then you only have to modify the value of the variable if they change again in the future. Like,

```
final int numberCount = 1000;
final int max = 99;
int[] counts = new int[max + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++) {
    counts[(int) (Math.random() * (max + 1))]++;
}
System.out.println("Count for each number between 0 and 9:");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + "s: " + counts[i]);
}
```